# How to migrate content from Django CMS to Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, migration, django-cms

I want to migrate content from Django CMS to WordPress but can't find any resource which would help regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the scale of your website it may be difficult to migrate it on your own. There is no automated "plugin" which can help you migrate all your blog posts / products / pages etc. If your website is big in scale and you are not confident in doing everything on your own you can hire an agency to do so. Upon searching the first result on google is this service provider: [Multidots](https://www.multidots.com/django-to-wordpress-migration/)

Cannot recommend them as I have never used them but you can at least get a quote for this. Manual migration may take some time but it would be worth it. What you can do is create all your pages, posts, products in Wordpress which essentially is not a hard process. It is important to keep your link structure the same or have proper redirects in order to keep your SEO score and not have 404 errors.

Comment: I found out about a couple of service providers too thought no luck in finding a plugin or such, before posting the question. Anyway thanks!!